# Trying to use a value converter with a ListView (Recycle Caching Strategy) with OnBindingContextChanged

Tags: xamarin.forms

Not sure if I formatted the question appropriately, please let me know if I did not. But I am trying to simply bind a background color to a value in my viewcell. I have this working, actually. The issue is when I update a value, I don't see the change in background color. The implementation is a bit complicated, but here's my code.

ViewCell (OnBindingContextChanged)

```
...
ShowReadOverlay.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty, new Xamarin.Forms.Binding(".", Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.TwoWay, new XamarinMobile.Converters.GridCellBackgroundColorConverter(), null, null, null));
...
```

So essentially I just build my layout. I decided to only post the relevant code that sets the binding in my `OnBindingContextChanged` method. If anyone needs any other code I'd be glad to add it, just don't know if it's relevant. My ViewCell class is a simple class that just inherits `ViewCell`.

Here's my converter:

```
public class GridCellBackgroundColorConverter : Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {

            var cell = (XamarinMobile.ViewModels.GridCellViewModel)value;

            if(cell.HasRead)
            {
                //return with shadow
                return Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromRgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            } else
            {
                //return no shadow
                return Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
            }

        } catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Simple. It works. Now here's the tricky part. So the grid I'm describing, is a listview that contains cells of stories. A user will click on an image which will take them to a story page. When the user is in the story page, they can either go back to the grid to go to another story, or swipe left or right and they can get to another story that way. When a user goes to a story page from our grid, then the cell gets updated fine. BUT if a user swipes to another story NOT from the grid, that's where my issue is. In my story page I have logic that iterates through the grid cells, and finds the story you're currently on (the story you swiped to) and sees if it's in the grid, if it's in the grid, I update the cell's `HasRead` property. As such:

```
            //find the cell in the grid (if exists)
            ViewModels.GridCellViewModel cell = App.GridCells.Where(x => x.StoryId == App.Story.StoryId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (cell != null)
            {
                cell.HasRead = true;
            }
```

This works but... it doesn't trigger the value converter to change the property. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it so that I can update a property, and have it trigger my value converter?

Comment: nothing? damn.. not even a little insight on how to bind a viewcell via onbindingcontext change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're converter isn't triggering because you've technically bound to the viewcell itself, not the HasRead property. When you set HasRead, it will (assuming it's implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) fire a PropertyChangedEvent which would trigger the binding and call the value converter. However, since your binding is pointing to the viewcell itself, it will only trigger when that changes and ignore property changes elsewhere on that object.

A possible solution is to change the binding to point to HasRead (instead of '.'), and update your converter to expect the boolean directly rather than taking in a viewcell. This would be a better practice for a converter regardless.

That said, this is not really following the mvvm pattern that is generally recommended for xamarin forms apps. My suggestion would be to have a viewmodel that has a property that holds your story models (wrapped in their own StoryViewModels if you need logic there) and make sure the VM and Model classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Make the VM the datacontext for the page, bind the list to your listview source and your listview itemtemplate contents will bind to each individual story. Each story can have a HasRead property that binds to the background color via your updated converter.

Like this:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="Stack_Stories.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stack_Stories">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:StoriesViewModel x:Name="VM" />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:StoryReadBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="HasReadColor" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Stories}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid x:Name="StoryGrid" BackgroundColor="{Binding HasRead, Converter={StaticResource HasReadColor}}">
                    <Button Command="{Binding ToggleReadCommand}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```
    public class StoryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private bool _hasRead = false;
    public bool HasRead
    {
        get { return _hasRead; }
        set { _hasRead = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private Command _toggleRead;
    public Command ToggleReadCommand    
    {
        get
        {
            return _toggleRead
                ?? (_toggleRead = new Command(() => HasRead = !HasRead));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public class StoriesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public StoriesViewModel()
    {
        // add sample stories
        Stories.Add(new StoryViewModel { Name = "First Story" });
        Stories.Add(new StoryViewModel { Name = "Second Story", HasRead=true });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<StoryViewModel> _stories = new ObservableCollection<StoryViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<StoryViewModel> Stories
    {
        get { return _stories; }
        set { _stories = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class StoryReadBackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool)) return null;

        return (bool)value ? Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) : Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I bound it to my viewmodel and, voila! Worked like a charm. Kind of confusing though since it's weird the layout is being setr in the ViewCell, but changes when you update the view model. Nevertheless, I took a similar approach so I marked your answer :)